# How bash interprets control operators

Tags: bash, environment-variables, control-flow

To run Rust program with a backtrace one should set environment variable RUST_BACKTRACE to one and run the program, so my first guess as inexperienced bash user was:

```
$ RUST_BACKTRACE=1 && cargo run
...
note: Run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` for a backtrace.
```

but there are no backtrace in the output. So, let's check if variable is set:

```
RUST_BACKTRACE=1 && echo $RUST_BACKTRACE && cargo run
1
...
note: Run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` for a backtrace.
```

and finally working solution would be:

```
RUST_BACKTRACE=1 cargo run
```

Please explain to me how it works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two possibilities how an external program sees that variable in its environment:

**export it for that command**

```
RUST_BACKTRACE=1 cargo run
```

In this case the variable is not part of the shell. If it was before then its value is not changed.

**export it**

The shell does not automatically export all its variables to programs it runs (not all shell variables are intended as part of an environment).

1. ```
   export RUST_BACKTRACE=1
   # or
   declare -x RUST_BACKTRACE=1
   cargo run
   ```
2. ```
   RUST_BACKTRACE=1
   export RUST_BACKTRACE
   # or
   declare -x RUST_BACKTRACE
   cargo run
   ```
3. ```
   set -a # Each  variable  or  function that is created or modified is given the export attribute
   RUST_BACKTRACE=1
   cargo run
   ```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, before I accept it, I have more small question. Please, explain to me what happens with env variables when I use `&&` to chain commands? The second example in the question makes no sense to me, why `echo` displays the variable, but `cargo` does not see it?

Comment: @gasabr `&&` and `||` have no effect on variables at all. `echo` does not consider its environment variables (it is not even an external command). The shell transforms `echo $foo` to `echo bar` before executing `echo`. The command cannot know whether there were shell variables involved. It only sees its command line arguments (not those you type but those which get executed in the end).